# Any way of knowing if hostel will be busy in advance?

Tags: hostels, south-america

I'm traveling through South America for 6 months. I'm now in week 2 of my trip and 3rd hostel. I've met some people in the hostels but only one or two. They all have good reviews online but are fairly empty. Apparently it's low season now. This surprises me as I would still have expected to see fellow travelers from all over the world in these hostels. My current hostel is a surf and yoga one and is cool but there are currently only two more guests!

I'm in the Rio de Janeiro area until Sunday then my plan is to visit Ilha Grande for 3nights, then Florinopolis, Igazu, Montevideo, Buenos Aires and then head south to Patagonia and then back up stopping en route to Columbia.

Should I alter my route and do it in reverse? Or is there any way of knowing if my planned route will have other travelers to hang out with?

Comment: Your best bet would be to call the hostel you plan on staying at and ask them if it's a busy time of year.

Comment: Maybe you're picking the wrong hostels - I was there around this time of year and met a lot of people! America Del Sur hostel in BA and El Calafate, Che Legarto(?) in Iguazu - those were great when I was there.